# "zoid destroyed all error" from paypal integration with ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, paypal

I'm getting an error that says zoid destroyed all when the paypal buttons try to load on my ruby-on-rails project. When I initially load the project directly to the payment page the buttons work but anytime I navigate off that page and back on I get the error. After some research it seems to be from a javascript library that paypal is using called krakenjs. I've read that there might be an issue with loading the paypal library multiple times which would explain why it works the first time but not after that. Would appreciate any insight.

application.html.erb - this is where the paypal javascript library is included in the header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sweepstakes</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stripe_javascript_tag %>

    <div class = "navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contributions", orders_path %></li>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <li class = "profile-drpdwn">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn"><%= current_user.email %></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %>
              <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
            </div>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li id = "navbar" class = "navbar-fr"><%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %></li>
          <li id = "navbar" class = "navbar-fr"><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=<%=ENV['PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID']%>&components=buttons"></script>
  </head>

  <% if notice %>
    <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
  <% end %>
  <% if alert %>
    <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
  <% end %>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.html.erb of the orders page where the paypal button is rendered

```
<div class = "formdiv">
  <h1>Contribution Options</h1>
  <%= form_tag({:controller => "orders", :action => "submit" }, {:id => 'order-details'}) do %>
    <input id="order-type" name="orders[payment_gateway]" type="hidden" value="stripe">
    <div class="form_row">
        <h4>Charges/Payments</h4>
        <% @contributions_purchase.each do |contribution| %>
          <div data-charges-and-payments-section = true>
          <%= radio_button_tag 'orders[contribution_id]', contribution.id, @contributions_purchase.first == contribution %>
          <span id="radioButtonName<%= contribution.id %>"><%= contribution.name %></span>
          <span data-price="<%= contribution.price_cents %>" id="radioButtonPrice<%= contribution.id %>"><%= number_to_currency(contribution.price) %></span>
          </div>
          <br>
        <% end %>
        <h4>Subscriptions</h4>
        <% @contributions_subscription.each do |contribution| %>
          <div>
            <%= radio_button_tag 'orders[contribution_id]', contribution.id, false %>
            <span id="radioButtonName<%= contribution.id %>"><%= contribution.name %></span>
            <span data-price="<%= contribution.price_cents %>" id="radioButtonPrice<%= contribution.id %>"><%= number_to_currency(contribution.price) %></span>
          </div>
          <br/>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <keep-alive>
    <h1>Payment Method</h1>
    <div class="form_row">
      <div>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'payment-selection', 'stripe', true, onclick: "changeTab();" %>
        <span>Stripe</span>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'payment-selection', 'paypal', false, onclick: "changeTab();" %>
        <span>Paypal</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="paymentSelectionTab active" id="tab-stripe">
      <div id="card-element"></div>
      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <%= submit_tag "Submit", id: "submit-stripe" %>
    </div>
    <div class="paymentSelectionTab" id="tab-paypal">
      <div id="submit-paypal"></div>
    </div>
    </keep-alive>
    <br>
    <br>
  <% end %>
</div>

<script>
  try {
    console.log("script working")
    function changeTab() {
      console.log("changeTab working")
      var newActiveTabID = $('input[name="payment-selection"]:checked').val();
      $('.paymentSelectionTab').removeClass('active');
      $('#tab-' + newActiveTabID).addClass('active');
    }

    function setupStripe() {
      console.log("setupStripe working")
      //Initialize stripe with publishable key
      // {ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY']}
      var stripe = Stripe("<%= ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] %>");

      //Create Stripe credit card elements.
      var elements = stripe.elements();
      var card = elements.create('card');

      //Add a listener in order to check if
      card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        console.log("event listener working")
        //the div card-errors contains error details if any
        var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        document.getElementById('submit-stripe').disabled = false;
        if (event.error) {
          console.log("card error")
          // Display error
          displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
        } else {
          console.log("No card error")
          // Clear error
          displayError.textContent = '';
        }
      });

      // Mount Stripe card element in the #card-element div.
      card.mount('#card-element');
      var form = document.getElementById('order-details');
      // This will be called when the #submit-stripe button is clicked by the user.
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        console.log("Submit event lister added")
        $('#submit-stripe').prop('disabled', true);
        event.preventDefault();
        stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
          if (result.error) {
            console.log("error on button press")
            // Inform that there was an error.
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
          } else {
            console.log("no error on button press")
            // Now we submit the form. We also add a hidden input storing 
            // the token. So our back-end can consume it.
            var $form = $("#order-details");
            // Add a hidden input orders[token]
            $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="orders[token]"/>').val(result.token.id));
            // Set order type
            $('#order-type').val('stripe');
            $form.submit();
          }
        });
        return false;
      });
    };

    function setupPaypal() {
      console.log("setupPaypal working")
      function isPayment() {
        console.log("isPayment")
        return $('[data-charges-and-payments-section] input[name="orders[contribution_id]"]:checked').length
      }

      function submitOrderPaypal(chargeID) {
        var $form = $("#order-details");
        // Add a hidden input orders[charge_id]
        console.log("check 1")
        console.log(chargeID)
        console.log("Check 2")
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="orders[charge_id]"/>').val(chargeID));
        // Set order type
        $('#order-type').val('paypal');
        $form.submit();
      }

      paypal.Buttons({
        env: "<%= ENV['PAYPAL_ENV'] %>",
        createOrder: function() {
          $('#order-type').val("paypal");
          if (isPayment()) {
            console.log("if isPayment")
            return $.post("<%= paypal_create_payment_url %>", $('#order-details').serialize()).then(function(data) {
              return data.token;
            });
          } else {
            console.log("else isPayment")
          }
        },
        onApprove: function(data) {
          if (isPayment()) {
            console.log("onApprove")
            return $.post("<%= paypal_execute_payment_url %>", {
              paymentID: data.paymentID,
              payerID:   data.payerID
            }).then(function() {
              console.log(data.paymentID)
              submitOrderPaypal(data.paymentID)
            });
          } else {
            console.log("else")
          }
        return buttonComp
        }
      }).render('#submit-paypal');
    };
    setupStripe()
    setupPaypal()
  } catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this. I have the exact same problem only in ReactJS

Comment: I've faced this issue twice in React. First time was because of how React behaves in dev mode: [rendering functional components with `useState()` twice](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074). So `paypal.Button().render()` was being called twice. I added a sentinel to make sure that the button was only rendered once. The second time is right now, which is why I'm here looking for a solution. But my code was working last week; I suspect the PayPal team has broken their Sandbox (has happened to me before). Instead of changing previously working code, I think I'll test it again tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you define paypal script link before javascript_pack_tag which is look like this:

```html
<!-- Paypal SDK -->
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=CLIENT_ID&vault=true"></script>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'admin', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'admin', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

in your application.js add paypal script to turbolinks:load function

```js
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  paypal.Buttons({
    createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.subscription.create({
        'plan_id': 'P-SOME-PLAN-ID'
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID);
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by turning turbolinks off for links to the paypal subscription page. So the link which takes the user to the paypal page looks something like this:

```
<a href="[paypal_page]" data-turbolinks="false">
```

For a page which tends only to be visited once by a user it has proved an acceptable workaround for us.